# Do I have to create separate page for Mobile and PC

Tags: html, css

I created a page in html page from my PC here is the link http://evaluations.tk/.
My question is do I have create separate page for both mobile and pc, if I have to create separate page then how can I set different previews for pc and phone. For testing I added meta tag but when I see that page on phone it make the objects very large. Can anyone help me...

Comment: You have already addes some 'responsive' behaviour. Nowadays, most have the same page to render multiple screens and devices. And using CSS (frameworks like bootstrap / foundation) to handle the responsive flows. Have a look at the viewport meta to solve your problem with the bigger objects. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 0):

No need to change in program.but you need to apply bootstrap css to all pages.

Bootstrap basically does is adjust the size of page as per the size of the screen..

Thanks Vote :P

Answer (score 0):

Like Yogesh Suthar's answer; bootstrap is your friend when dealing with responsiveness of your websites. By the use of the column grid structure, you can make your site responsive to different screen sizes. If you would like to have some more customisation, you can also create bootstrap-like behaviour with css by employing media queries (e.g. `@media screen and (min-width: 400px){color: red;}`). Basically, you define the layout for mobile first and then gradually add styling for larger screen sizes.